# Docker run errors on passing a dash as an argument?

Tags: docker, command, arguments, line, dash-shell

I need to pass `-Dfml.queryResult=confirm` to the executable of an otherwise working docker container (on the docker run line), but all I get is : `-Dfml.queryResult=confirm: invalid syntax`  ...  I've tried with quotes, no quotes, single quotes, escaping it, everything I can think of, and I've put it behind `-c` as suggested here, but I always get an error.  Am I missing something silly?

Comment: Are u using entrypoint or command?

Comment: Please post ur dockerfile.